# None express about python regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I want to filter all "wub"s in a string
For example
"wubwubwubIwubwubwubAmwubwubHere" --> I Am Here

Firstly I tried `re.split(r'wub',string)`and result was `['', '', '', 'I', '', '', 'AM', '', 'Here']`. Some none elements appeared. And I have to add a `filter` to delete those none elements. I wonder is there a direct method of regular express that could filter all "wub"s without leaving none elements?

like this
`re.split(r'\s+', 'a b   c')` --> ['a', 'b', 'c']

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following to match:

```
(wub)+
```

And replace with `(space)`

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this alone with single regex.

```
>>> s = "wubwubwubIwubwubwubAmwubwubHere"
>>> re.sub(r'(?:wub)+', ' ', s).strip()
'I Am Here'
```

OR

```
>>> ' '.join(i for i in re.split(r'(?:wub)+', s) if i)
'I Am Here'
```

Comment: since you're new to Stack Overflow, i suggest you to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)